# why am I getting this error : data structures (arrays)?

Tags: java, arrays, structure

I basically need to find the number of sub arrays that have a negative sum.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    static int add(int a[]) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            sum = sum + a[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Enter your code here.
         * Read input from STDIN.
         * Print output to STDOUT.
         * Your class should be named Solution.
         */
        int count = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
            arr[k] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j) {
                int slice[] = IntStream.range(j, j + i + 1).map(j -> arr[j]).toArray();
                if (add(slice) < 0) {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Compile Message

```
Solution.java:32: error: variable j is already defined in method main(String[])
int slice[] = IntStream.range(j, j + i + 1).map(j -> arr[j]).toArray();
                                                ^
1 error
Exit Status
255
```

Comment: Just replace it with some non-existing variable name : `map(foo -> arr[foo])`

Comment: `j` is already the variable used for iteration inside the nested loop; you have to pick another name for the variable inside the call to `map`.

Comment: j is already defined in the scope so you need to use an Unique name for the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the scope of the variable `j` here. When you refer a variable in map, JVM tries to initiliaze this. In your case, JVM is trying to initialize j with the contents of the map but it is already available at that point from your second for loop. Just use any other variable such as 'k' to get it done.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
static int add(int a[])
{
    int sum= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    int count = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        arr[k] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j)
        {
            int slice[] = IntStream.range(j, j + i + 1).map(k -> arr[k]).toArray();
            if(add(slice) < 0)
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line declares a variable `j` which is already declared as the loop counter in that scope:

```
int slice[] = IntStream.range(j, j + i + 1).map(j -> arr[j]).toArray();
```

You will have to give it a differen name to get rid of this compilation error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // this is where j is defined for the loop scope
    for (int j = 0; j < n - i; ++j) {
        // replace the j inside the .map(...)
        int slice[] = IntStream.range(j, j + i + 1).map(s -> arr[s]).toArray();
        if (add(slice) < 0) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
}
```